# Pdf not displayed in mobile displays

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have to display a pdf file in my web page. Currently I am using the following code for pdf display:-

```
<div id="bill_pdf" class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    <object data="{{bill_details[0].bill_url}}?#zoom=50&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&embedded=true" id="bill_pdf_link" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>
```

Currently it is getting properly displayed in laptop screen. I need the following more requirement:-

1) It does not show up on mobile browser. I am certain that object tag should show up in safari browser for ios but it does not. Do I need to change something so that the pdf is also loaded in mobile displays.

2) I want a download button on the pdf that usually comes up in sites now a days if we want to save the pdf to our computer.

Comment: Try using an iframe that points to the pdf file instead.

Comment: iframe is not working for me because I am getting the src of pdf from angular js scope variable.

Comment: did you use `ng-src` on the iframe to use with the variable?

Comment: With iframe i just get a greyed screen and the following error:-Refused to display 'https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-114hr5926rh/pdf/BILLS-114hr5926rh.pdf' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.